# Why a TCP socket server written in C should not close client file descriptors in worker pthreads, but can close them in forked worker processes?

Tags: c, sockets, server, pthreads, file-descriptor

I wrote a simple TCP socket server in C, which creates a new child worker thread when it accepts a new connection request from a client and simply counts and sends numbers. If a client terminates, the corresponding child worker thread should also terminate, while the other threads should not.

If all clients are written in Python, when a client terminates, "Connection is reset by peer" is printed on the server, but everything else is fine, that is, other threads and clients are still working.

But if a client is written in C, when any clients and their corresponding child worker threads terminate, other threads also terminate, which is not expected. Why does it happen? I rewrote the server in Python, but this did not happen no matter what language the client is written in.

I then commented out `close(*client_fd);` and the issue is solved. I haven't got a clue, since it works fine in the server using `fork()`.

The C code for server using `pthread` is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define PORT 9000
#define CONNECTIONS 2
#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 1024

struct sockaddr_in socket_address;
socklen_t socket_address_size = sizeof(socket_address);
int server_fd;

void *handle_request(void *fd) {
    int *client_fd = (int *) fd;
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};

    for (int i = INT_MAX; send(*client_fd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0) >= 0 && i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%d\r\n", i);
        sprintf(buffer, "%d", i);
    }

    if (close(*client_fd) < 0) {
        perror("close client_fd");
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int option = 1;
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};

    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &option, sizeof(option))) {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    socket_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socket_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    socket_address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &socket_address, socket_address_size) < 0) {
        perror("bind");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (listen(server_fd, CONNECTIONS) < 0) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pthread_t threads[CONNECTIONS];
    int client_fds[CONNECTIONS];
    for (int i = 0; i < CONNECTIONS; i++) {
        client_fds[i] = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &socket_address, &socket_address_size);
        if (client_fds[i] < 0) {
            perror("accept");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, handle_request, &client_fds[i]) < 0) {
            perror("pthread_create");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < CONNECTIONS; i++) {
        if (pthread_join(threads[i], NULL) < 0) {
            perror("pthread_join");
        }
    }

    close(server_fd);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The C code for server using `fork()` is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define PORT 9000
#define CONNECTIONS 2
#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct sockaddr_in socket_address;
    socklen_t socket_address_size = sizeof(socket_address);
    int server_fd, client_fd, option = 1;
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};

    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &option, sizeof(option))) {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    socket_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socket_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    socket_address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &socket_address, socket_address_size) < 0) {
        perror("bind");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (listen(server_fd, CONNECTIONS) < 0) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pid_t pids[CONNECTIONS];
    for (int i = 0; i < CONNECTIONS; i++) {
        pids[i] = fork();
        if (pids[i] < 0) {
            perror("fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else if (pids[i] == 0) {
            if ((client_fd = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &socket_address, &socket_address_size)) < 0) {
                perror("accept");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            for (int i = INT_MAX; send(client_fd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0) >= 0 && i >= 0; i--) {
                printf("%d\r\n", i);
                sprintf(buffer, "%d", i);
            }
            
            close(client_fd);
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < CONNECTIONS; i++) {
        int wstatus;
        if (waitpid(0, &wstatus, WUNTRACED) < 0) {
            perror("waitpid");
        }
    }

    close(server_fd);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The C code for client is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define IP_ADDRESS "127.0.0.1"
#define PORT 9000
#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int socket_fd;
    struct sockaddr_in socket_address;
    socklen_t socket_address_size = sizeof(socket_address);
    ssize_t message_len;
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};

    if ((socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    socket_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socket_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP_ADDRESS);
    socket_address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if (connect(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &socket_address, socket_address_size) < 0) {
        perror("connect");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    while ((message_len = recv(socket_fd, buffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, 0)) > 0) {
        buffer[message_len] = '\0';
        puts(buffer);
    }

    close(socket_fd);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The Python code for server is as follows:

```
import socket
import threading

HOST = ''
PORT = 9000
CONNECTIONS = 2
TRUNK_SIZE = 1024

def handle_request(connection):
    with connection:
        count = 0
        while True:
            state = connection.send(f'{count}\r\n'.encode('utf-8'))
            if not state:
                print(f"Connection closed from {address}.")
                break
            print(count)
            count += 1

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR | socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(CONNECTIONS)
    threads = []
    for c in range(CONNECTIONS):
        connection, address = s.accept()
        print(f'Connected by {address}.')
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_request, args=(connection,), daemon=True)
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```

The Python code for client is as follows:

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 9000
TRUNK_SIZE = 1024
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    while True:
        data = s.recv(TRUNK_SIZE).decode('utf-8')
        if not data:
            print("Connection closed.")
            break
        print(data)
```

Comment: Perhaps because resources (including sockets) in threads are shared by a single process? Closing a socket in one threads closes it for the whole process. If using worker processes then the sockets are separate from sockets in other processes, even if the processes was forked from the same parent process.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but why is that a problem here? That is the expected behaviour.

Comment: The title asked "why don't close in threads, but close in processes", and that's basically is the reason. Yes it's expected behavior, but not everyone know that yet.

Comment: accept creates a new socket. connection_handler should close that socket. There must be some other bug in the code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But the `client_fd` is different in each child worker thread. I think closing a socket in one thread shouldn't close it for the whole process?

Answer (score 0):

If your whole process suddenly goes down while writing to a socket, then due to a `SIGPIPE` signal you received (indicated by the error EPIPE). The standard action of `SIGPIPE` is to terminate the process. Implement a signal handler which will catch `SIGPIPE` signals (and probably ignore or deal with it).

The message "Connection is reset by peer" is an indication of a caught SIGPIPE signal.

Comment: One of the many problems with systemd is IgnoreSIGPIPE defaults to true.

Comment: @stark Well, i don't know if the OP has systemd on its system, but i still think that his process termination has to do with it. It's stated that there is no 'problem' with the forked version, because only that child process gets terminated instead of, like in the threaded version, the only process there is.

Comment: @stark But thanks nevertheless, i didn't know that.